# CSS: how to create responsive irregular shapes

Tags: css

I have created an irregular shape using css.
Now, my question is: how can I create the same shape, but responsive.

Here is the link:
https://jsfiddle.net/jobgaraux/rpfg64vq/

```
     #myForm{
 width: 800px;
height: 300px;
position: relative;
 background-color: #A0A0A0;
     color: #fff;
     font-size: 2.4em;
  font-weight: 700;

}  

...and so on
```

Comment: use gradients in percentages.

Comment: provide fiddle. All you have made is a rectangle? How is this an irregular shape?

Comment: Hi, I added a fiddle link

Comment: instead of 800px why didn't you try for some 80 or 90%? or use calc to set your pixels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#myForm{
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 800px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #A0A0A0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2.4em;
  font-weight: 700;      
}
     
          #myForm span{
   display:inline-block;
           vertical-align: middle;
}
  
     
     
     
 

#myForm::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 120px 800px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
}

#myForm::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 80px 300px 0;
  border-color: transparent #fff transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="myForm"></div>
```

Comment: use: max-width: 100%;

Comment: use: max-width: 100%;   or  @media only screen and(max-width: 800px){}