# How to create a vertical responsive left menu with different shapes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need this vertical menu design using HTML, CSS / Bootstrap / Jquery / Javascript that i can use for any Tablet devices with responsive height like in image.

Vertical responsive menu should be always 100% height in both landscape and portrait mode.

Vertical responsive menu design attached with this post for your reference.

[image: Vertical responsive Menu]

I tried the below code but I cannot center align the text in the boxes, border radius for boxes and vertical responsive for menu (100% height).

[Code help got from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39466391/css-how-to-create-responsive-irregular-shapes)

```css
.myForm {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #A0A0A0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2.4em;
  font-weight: 700;

}
.myForm  font { 
  margin:0 auto; 
  padding:0; 
  font-size:13px; 
  color:#ffffff; 
  text-align:center;
}

.myForm span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.myForm::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.myForm::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 80px 300px 0;
  border-color: transparent #fff transparent transparent;
  border-radius:0px 0px 0px 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="myForm" style="background:#ff0000;"><font>Menu 1</font></div>
<div class="myForm" style="background:#0094ff;"><font>Menu 2</font></div>
<div class="myForm" style="background:#ff0000;"><font>Menu 3</font></div>
<div class="myForm" style="background:#0094ff;"><font>Menu 4</font></div>
```

Comment: Firstly, the `<font>` tag isn't supported as part of HTML5 so you might want to change that to something else. In terms of making the menu match the screen height, you need something like `html, body { margin: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; }` and then adding `height: 25%;` to `.myForm`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `vh` for vertical align depend on the **viewport** height. After font tag is pure `html`, for use this with specific `css` you can add `display:block`. I have use translate for align your text in center.

```css
.myForm {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 25vh;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #A0A0A0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2.4em;
  font-weight: 700;
  min-width:200px;          
}

.myForm  font { 
  margin:0 auto; 
  padding:0; 
  font-size:13px; 
  color:#ffffff; 
  top:50%;
  left:30%;
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.myForm span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.myForm::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;

}

.myForm::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 80px 300px 0;
    border-color: transparent #fff transparent transparent;
    border-radius:0px 0px 0px 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="myForm" style="background:#ff0000;"><font>Menu 1</font></div>
<div class="myForm" style="background:#0094ff;"><font>Menu 2</font></div>
<div class="myForm" style="background:#ff0000;"><font>Menu 3</font></div>
<div class="myForm" style="background:#0094ff;"><font>Menu 4</font></div>
```

Comment: can i have active triangle for current page like in menu 1 box in the attached image?

Comment: Come on man you gotta do coding yourself!!! there many article for what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
 .myForm {
      height: 25vh;
  }
```

use virtual heigh(vh) instead of px

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Pandiarajan with using vh. Then give your font position absolute and position it using left, top and transform rules.

Best of luck!

```
.myForm font {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
.myForm {
    height: 25vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution using the CSS trick found at this site:
http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/

Here is a link to the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/pcqamcrL/

```
.myForm {
   max-width: 100%;
   width: 200px;
   height: 100px;
   position: relative;
   background-color: #A0A0A0;
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 2.4em;
   font-weight: 700;
 }
.myForm  font { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    margin:0 auto; 
    padding:0; 
    font-size:13px; 
    color:#ffffff; 
    text-align:center;
 }

 .myForm::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 80px 300px 0;
    border-color: transparent #fff transparent transparent;
    border-radius:0px 0px 0px 30px;
 }

 <div class="myForm" style="background:#ff0000;"><font>Menu 1</font></div>
 <div class="myForm" style="background:#0094ff;"><font>Menu 2</font></div>
 <div class="myForm" style="background:#ff0000;"><font>Menu 3</font></div>
 <div class="myForm" style="background:#0094ff;"><font>Menu 4</font></div>
```